# Which versions of Safari support "srcdoc" in iframes?

Tags: html, safari

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) has a `?` in the compatibility table for iframe srcdoc.

I know at least the current version (v8) of Safari supports srcdoc, but I wanted to know which version started the support?

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be any mention of `srcdoc` in Apple's [Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Introduction/Introduction.html), despite it claiming to be "the best source of official up-to-date technical documentation on iOS, OS X, and Safari development".

The WebKit blog had a [post in April 2012](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1972/last-week-in-webkit-flexbox-updates-and-iframes-srcdoc-attribute) announcing support for `srcdoc`, implemented via [this changeset](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/113143). Based on its [release history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history), I would guess that support was introduced in Safari 6, which was released a few months later.

Unfortunately, I don't have Safari 6 on my Mac anymore to test this. However, I can confirm that it is absent from 5.1.7 on Windows, as I would expect.